# Converting NetCDF (.nc) file to raster and vector using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, netcdf

Using ArcGIS 10.4.1 for Desktop, I need to open NetCDF (.nc) file, which was obtained [here](https://www.bgc-jena.mpg.de/geodb/projects/Data.php).

This file is the product of GEOCARBON project.
To download this file:

> click the link above > choose “GEOCARBON” (abovethe “Download” button) >
>   Download > choose “Forest Aboveground Biomass map” > Download.

I also uploaded this file (`2016121233557Forest_Aboveground_Biomassv3.nc`) on my google disk, it can be downloaded (170.5 mb) via this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6TJ2VnOYaa1RkNGbzFLU3dqalE/view).

Here is the metadata of this file, which is given in the download process:

```
NcDump netcdf Forest_Aboveground_Biomassv3  
 { dimensions: 
    longitude = 36000 ; 
    latitude = 14002 ;  variables: 
    double longitude(longitude) ; 
    longitude:standard_name = "longitude" ; 
    longitude:long_name = "longitude" ; 
    longitude:units = "degrees_east" ; 
    longitude:axis = "X" ; 
    double latitude(latitude) ; 
    latitude:standard_name = "latitude" ; 
    latitude:long_name = "latitude" ; 
    latitude:units = "degrees_north" ; 
    latitude:axis = "Y" ; 
    float Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3(latitude, longitude) ;       
    Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3:long_name = "Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3" ; 
    Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3:_FillValue = -3.4e+38f ; 
    Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3:missing_value = -3.4e+38f ;
    Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3:projection = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84
+no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" ;  
    Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3:projection_format = "PROJ.4" ; 
    Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3:min = 0. ; 
    Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3:max = 611.399963378906 ;  // global attributes: 
    :CDI = "Climate Data Interface version 1.6.9 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)" ;
     :history = "Wed Sep 09 15:23:36 2015: cdo -f nc4c -z zip copy Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3.nc Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3_2.nc" ;
     :Conventions = "CF-1.4" ;
     :created_by = "R, packages ncdf and raster (version 2.2-31)" ;
     :date = "2015-08-31 14:39:27" ;
     :CDO = "Climate Data Operators version 1.6.9 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)" ; }[/quote]
```

And here is the description of the same file, which was obtained using the gdalinfo utility (the descriptions in both cases are a bit different):

```
> gdalinfo 2016121233557Forest_Aboveground_Biomassv3.nc 

Driver: HDF5Image/HDF5 
Dataset Files: 2016121233557Forest_Aboveground_Biomassv3.nc 
Size is 36000, 14002 Coordinate System is `' 
Metadata:   
    CDI=Climate Data Interface version 1.6.9 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)   
    CDO=Climate Data Operators version 1.6.9 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)   
    Conventions=CF-1.4   
    created_by=R, packages ncdf and raster (version 2.2-31)   
    date=2015-08-31 14:39:27   
    history=Wed Sep 09 15:23:36 2015: cdo -f nc4c -z zip copy Forest_Aboveground_B iomass_v3.nc Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3_2.nc
_nc3_strict=1 
Corner Coordinates: 
    Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0) 
    Lower Left  (    0.0,14002.0) 
    Upper Right (36000.0,    0.0) 
    Lower Right (36000.0,14002.0) 
    Center      (18000.0, 7001.0) 
Band 1 Block=36000x14002 
Type=Float32, 
ColorInterp=Undefined   
Metadata:
    Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3_long_name=Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3
    Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3_max=611.399963378906
    Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3_min=0
    Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3_missing_value=-3.4e+038
    Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3_projection=+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs  +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
    Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3_projection_format=PROJ.4
    Forest_Aboveground_Biomass_v3__FillValue=-3.4e+038
```

I need to open this file. I work with this format at first time and realize that it is not an ordinary task. As I understand, I can open it as raster and as vector. I want to open it using ArcGIS (I use ArcGIS 10.4.1).

ArcGIS has tools which should open the NetCDF files. There are two instruments  located in  the Multidimension Tools: ***Make NetCDF Raster Layer*** (to convert of NetCDF in raster) and ***Make NetCDF Feature Layer*** (to  convert NetCDF in vector).
Unfortunately I can’t open this file, because I don’t know what data about the file I should insert in the settings of these tools. The [ArcGIS Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/netcdf/reading-netcdf-data-as-a-raster-layer.htm) doesn’t help (it only repeats the general instructions)

Could you help me – WHAT data I should put in the settings of both tools (Make NetCDF Raster Layer, Make NetCDF Feature Layer ) for open this file correctly?

[Here is the print screen](https://z-1-scontent.fsst1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15317907_1620186518006949_257425760029144431_n.jpg?oh=5c03ed3676f6f660d7e2dd5fbc1934c3&oe=58BE266C) of the settings which I inserted in the “Make NetCDF Raster Layer” tool. This variant doesn’t work:

[image]

[Here is the print screen](https://z-1-scontent.fsst1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15390763_1620187024673565_7376315685937987356_n.jpg?oh=4963f2d4425a4f259f740041f062eb08&oe=58BC0BC0) of the settings which I inserted in “Make NetCDF Feature Layer” tool. This variant also doesn’t work:

[image]

Can somebody detect the proper settings for both ArcGIS tools according to the  metadata of this file?

Comment: Looks like you have provided the "what" - biomass_v3, the "where" - X and Y, you just need to provide the "when" for the dimension value.

Comment: Homydd, 
I used of various combinations - put the data from metadata in the settings of both tools. But I can't insert it correctly. They didn’t open the file.
There are  few of "dimension" looking  fields in the settings. Also I don't know what is the dimension in this file.
The best case if somebody can demonstrate the correct values of the parameters in the settings of these tools. I need the real example.  (I need to see which data of the metadata was inserted in which field of the settings). Unfortunately, the Help of ArcGIS doesn't give this example in the instructions for tools.

Comment: FWIW, here's a tutorial: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/netcdf-tutorial.pdf

Comment: With no one having offered an answer after 6 months, and there still being a comment made that has not been incorporated into your question, I think it may be time for you to use the [edit] button to heavily revise it.